# Using the FileHelpers nuget package to read barcodes

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Hello i'm using the FileHelpers nugets library to read from a barcode. Here's a sample of it :

```
(3102)011780(10)772890
```

and here is my filehelpers class :

```
class ReadBareCodes
{
    [FieldFixedLength(6)]
    public string cbDate;

    [FieldFixedLength(6)]
    public double poidsNet;

    [FieldFixedLength(4)]
    public string dix;

    [FieldFixedLength(6)]
    public string lot;
}
```

The field `poidsNet` always has 6 characters : `011780` but i want it to be like this : `0117,80`. So here's what i try :

```
private void ValidPdsNetBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string bareCode = BareCode_TxtBox.Text;
    string bareCodes_Path = @"O:\GT\GT9999 - Applications\G-Suite\Dossiers G-Suite\BareCodes_files\CB.txt";
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(bareCodes_Path, append: false))
    {
        sw.Write(bareCode);
    }


    FixedFileEngine<ReadBareCodes> engine = new FixedFileEngine<ReadBareCodes>();
    ReadBareCodes[] rst = engine.ReadFile(bareCodes_Path);

    foreach(var det in rst)
    {
        Messages.InformationMessage($"Date : {det.cbDate}\nPoids Net : {det.poidsNet.ToString("0.00")}\n_Dix : {det.dix}\nLot : {det.lot}");
    } 
}
```

But of course the output format looks like : `011780,00`, and that'not what i want.

Can someone put me into the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Custom converter](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/Converters/CustomConverter/) to modify how a field is converted. Here is a working program for your scenario.

```
class Program
{
    [FixedLengthRecord]
    class ReadBarCodes
    {
        [FieldFixedLength(6)]
        public string cbDate;

        [FieldFixedLength(6)]
        [FieldConverter(typeof(MyDoubleConverter))]
        public double poidsNet;

        [FieldFixedLength(4)]
        public string dix;

        [FieldFixedLength(6)]
        public string lot;
    }

    public class MyDoubleConverter : ConverterBase
    {
        public override object StringToField(string from)
        {
            // When importing, 'from' will contain the string from the file "011780"
            return Convert.ToDouble(Double.Parse(from) / 100);
        }

        public override string FieldToString(object fieldValue)
        {
            // When exporting, do the opposite: remove the decimal point.
            return ((double)fieldValue).ToString("#.##").Replace(".", "");
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fileContent = "(3102)011780(10)772890";

        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ReadBarCodes>();
        var records = engine.ReadString(fileContent);

        if (records[0].poidsNet == 117.80)
            Console.WriteLine("The poidsNet field was correctly read as 117.80.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to read poidsNet correctly.");

        Console.WriteLine("OK");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```